# VueJS 2.0 my web app doesn't show up its source in chrome View Page Source

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

When my webapp is loaded I'm not able to see the rendered HTML of all my components, this is some **webpack sourcemap** feature? When I started the project I used the webpack simple initializer from vue-cli.

The problem is ut only renders this node, I'd like to see all my rendered HTML of all my pages:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Let me know if more details is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with that vue dev tools extension for chrome browser:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, actually I'm able to debug through Chrome Dev Tools. My point is that my webapp must follow SEO patterns and for that I need to expose all my HTML on View Page Source.

Comment: so maybe this can get your tool: https://nuxtjs.org/guide
it's for pre-rendering your site / app.

Comment: Yeah I knew about it, unfortunately a framework that I use is not compatible with nuxt yet, I'm trying other alternatives such PreRenderSeo with Webpack.

Comment: I'm also interested in creating a SEO compatible website in an app way.

I assume vue should run on top of your let's say CMS and fetch data via ajax. So the pre-rendering could happen like you did it before.

Comment: Yeah actually there is a npm plugin called spa-prerender-plugin which allows you to create it, I did a POC to test it https://github.com/felipekm/vuejs-pre-render